# Swagger.json is displayed but the UI not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

I have ASP.Net 6.0 project and I have configured Swagger as follows:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
        Title = "MyApi",
        Version = "v1"
    });
    c.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(x => x.First());
});
```

and:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
#if DEBUG
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
#else
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/MyApp/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
#endif
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

The `swagger.json` is being served from the correct endpoint. But the UI endpoint returns `404 Not Found`.

What is the correct way to show the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, I feel that this may be an option that needs to be optimized. Your code is correct, but now we encountered strange behavior.

So I analyzed, why does `c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` not take effect in VS2022 at startup? But when I directly access `https://localhost:port`, the function is normal.

This seems to be related to the settings in VS2022, so I found the settings below and found the settings for Url.

[image]

Then I delete the `swagger` value, and the issue was fixed.

Comment: I spent way too long looking for this, thanks!